# How to set Title & Content of Notification?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm trying to send a notification to the user when a new message arrives.

I can send notifications, but I have some problems with customizing my notification.

Here is my code for creating notificationChannel :

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NotificationName",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("Test channel");

            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 2000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
```

Here is code for creating notification :

```java
notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate((new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 2000}))
                .setStyle((new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle() ) )
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Unread message")
                .setContentText("You have an unread message")
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bildirimDeneme.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

I am setting the content text to "You have an unread message". But notification appears like this [1]: https://hizliresim.com/EO6rVB

So there is no content at all.

Comment: use notitification styles https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Style

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me which style I should choose? I read the page on the link, but no matter which style I use, it looks like it has titles and contents. I tried using Notification.BigTextStyle but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to set the content to the InboxStyle like that:

```
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
     .setContentTitle("Title")
     .addLine("Hello")
     .addLine("World")
     .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you may *"play"* with the ***setStyle*** method showing a big text and letting the Notification API do the job

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_upload)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notif_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notif_subject))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(*your_message*))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```